Integrating FTP (Netconn API) with MQTT (Raw API) on LwIP in Bare-Metal Environment. Will that be possible without any conflicts or overheads?
I have been working with the LwIP in my embedded systems project. I have successfully implemented MQTT using the LwIP raw API in a bare-metal environment (NO_SYS = 1). Now, I need to integrate an FTP protocol, which is based on the LwIP netconn API, to transfer around 40MB of error record files to My PC,
Given that both protocols will be running concurrently in this bare-metal setup without an operating system, are there any potential conflicts or issues I should be aware of when combining the raw API with the netconn API in the same firmware?
I’ve already implemented MQTT using the LwIP raw API, which is working successfully in my bare-metal setup. Now, I'm exploring the integration of FTP library, which utilizes the LwIP netconn API. However, before proceeding with the integration, I wanted to ensure that combining these two APIs (raw and netconn) in a single project won't lead to conflicts, especially given the absence of an operating system (NO_SYS = 1).
